# Tetrahedral division of a polyhedron with triangle faces

Tags: geometry

Let $P$ be a polyhedron with triangle faces.
We divide $P$ and inside it to tetrahedrons, consistent with the triangle faces.
We denote the edge inside $P$ which has even number of tetrahedrons around it by even inner edge.
See the example: tetrahedral division of decahedron.
Generalizing it, I propose the following.

Is there a tetrahedral division with even inner edges inside any polyhedron with triangle faces or is there any condition for the tetrahedral division of a polyhedron with triangle faces?[image: Decahedron]

If a polyhedron with triangle faces has a tetrahedral division with even inner edges, it is $4$ colorable.